# How to download a particular files in php

Tags: php

I'm unable to download a particular record after fetching the records from the database.
If I use this code I can download only that file, but after fetching the data if I click on any download button only that particular file related to that record should be downloaded.

Here is my code:

---

HTML:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">S.No</th>
         <th scope="col" style="align:center;">Title</th>
         <th scope="col">Image</th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 95px;">Modify</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php include "image.php" ;
         while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      ?>    
      <?php 
         $r=$row['blog_title'];
         $string=str_replace('-',' ', $r);
      ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['blog_id'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $string;?></td>
         <td><?php if($row['image']) echo "<img src='upload/".$row['image']."' height='100' weight='100' />"; ?></td>
         <td><a class="buttons delete" href="deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo $row['blog_id'];?>" >Delete Blog</a></td>
         $file = "logo_ldg.png";
         <td><a class="buttons delete" href="download.php?nama=".$file."' >Download</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
         }
      ?>   
   </tbody>
</table>
```

---

download.php

```
<?php
    $name= $_GET['nama'];

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\";");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile("your_file_path/".$name); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: The filename is hardcoded as `$file = "logo_ldg.png";`. If this should come from the database, you must update your code.

Comment: `<a class="buttons delete" href="download.php?nama=".$file."' >` contains a quotes mismatch also.

Comment: `readfile` and `filesize` use different paths to your file.